# Is it possible to influence the seasons?

Tags: mario-kart-8

The new Animal Crossing DLC introduces the *Animal Crossing* track which features 4 different seasons that are seemingly chosen at random.

After racing through the track about 7 times, I've seen spring, summer, and winter, but not autumn; each season (except autumn) appeared twice, with summer appearing three times.

Is there any way I can influence the seasons in such a way that I can finally race in autumn?

Comment: Link was in the previous DLC. If only he had [come prepared](http://zeldawiki.org/Rod_of_Seasons).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the track changes season every time it is played without any rule, it's just randomized. At the moment there are no official evidence to prove that.

It's like [Excitebike Arena](http://www.mariowiki.com/Excitebike_Arena), whose layout changes every time a race starts.